# magic fields 2 // way to emulate write panel?

Tags: wordpress

So Magic Fields 2 doesn't have "write panels."  and since MF2 is so sleek - I am thinking there is some other thing that takes it's place that I can't find.

problem is this:  creating a simple page with some fields in it.

**in MF1//**

1. create some m-Fields
2. create a page
3. fill out the fields on the page
4. select the fields that i want as a write panel.
5. echo them out on the page

STRUCTURE:  page>fields

**in MF2//**

1. create a page template
2. create a page
3. assign the template to the page
4. create a custom post type
5. create the fields for that post type
6. create a post
7. fill in all the fields
8. run a loop in the page for the post type (for  1 post)
9. echo out the m-Fields data

STRUCTURE:   page>post>fields

so a client would have to select the post type "about" then go in there and get(the only post in there) "about" then adjust the fields... meanwhile the page "about" is never touched... seems really strange...

or --- you could put ALL of the magic-fields on "page" - which in my case would mean that there would be 100 plus fields on every page and 90 of them wouldn't have to do with that page and then couldn't be required --- which is all way too confusing for clients.

I feel like I'm just not checking a special box somewhere.

Comment: i found this   https://github.com/magic-fields-team/Magic-Fields-2/issues/5

Comment: but i still think there is a way to do what I need... without having to make 3 things where I used to make 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just NO.

I have since started using Advance Custom Fields plugin and you just set up your custom field sets and tell them what page or post type to appear on. I have more confidence that ACF will stay up to date then the other plug in options. Just wanted to throw that out there.